# Angular set dynamic class based on element being in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set a class based on whether or not an object exists in an array. Something like:

```
<button ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-click="addItem(item)"
        ng-class="{'selected': selectedFilter(item)}">{{item.name}}</button>

$scope.items = [
  {name: 'apple', prop: 1},
  {name: 'banana', prop: 2},
  {name: 'orange', prop: 3}     
];
$scope.selectedItems = [
  {name: 'apple', prop: 1}
];
$scope.addItem = function(item){
  $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
};
$scope.selectedFilter = function(item){
  $scope.selectedItems.forEach(function(selectedItem){
    return selectedItem.name===item.name
  });
};
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/misetayuva/edit?html,css,js,output)

The idea is that when a button is clicked and an item is selected, I would think that the class would be applied and the color should turn to gray. However nothing is happening. And no error.

Comment: Is it because your class being applied is `selecte` instead of `selected`?

Comment: @NateAnderson No, I've just gone through and cleaned up a bunch of typos like that.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
    <button ng-repeat="item in items"
        ng-click="addItem(item)"
        ng-class="{'selected': item.name == selectedItemName }">
    {{item.name}}
</button>
```

with this

```
        $scope.addItem = function (item) {
            $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
            $scope.selectedItemName = item.name;
        };

        $scope.selectedItemName = 'apple';
```

You can get rid of this function:

```
$scope.selectedFilter = function(item){
  $scope.selectedItems.forEach(function(selectedItem){
    return selectedItem.name===item.name
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Array.prototype.find` in this case. The `return` value for `Array.prototype.forEach` is always `undefined`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
$scope.selectedFilter = function(item){
  !!$scope.selectedItems.find(function(selectedItem){
        return selectedItem.name === item.name;
      });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonice2004/nx4mmb04/) that I included that shows how to set the css for items when selected. Just to make it complete, I also included a code that will remove the items from the selection list when it is clicked again.

This code will mark the elements in `$scope.items` as `IsSelected = true` initially and it will update the selection status on each item when the click happens. I have used the color green for selected item (Hope you don't mind).

```
function markSelectedItems() {
$scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
  $scope.selectedItems.forEach(function(selectedItem) {
    return selectedItem.name === item.name ? item.IsSelected = true : false;
  });
});
```

}

```
$scope.addItem = function(item) {
if (!item.IsSelected) {
  $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
  item.IsSelected = true;
} else {
  var indexToRemove = -1;
  var count = $scope.selectedItems.length;
  //removes the first match
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if ($scope.selectedItems[i].name === item.name) {
      $scope.selectedItems.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  item.IsSelected = false;
}
```

};